# c# using reflection to access members of a nested structure

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using C# reflection to implement a scripting language that allows the user to have access to internal program variables.

It works for simple constructs, but when I try to access data in instantiated structures, it always gives 0 as the data value.
My test program:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public class TST         // Test class
    {
        public struct S1_t
        {
            public UInt32 one;
            public UInt32 two;
        }
        public S1_t t1 = new S1_t();
        public UInt32 x;
        public TST()
        {
            t1.one = 6977;
            t1.two = 2;
            x = 7769;
        }
    }

    public class NFC
    {
        public TST tst = new TST();
    }

    public class PRD
    {
        public NFC nfc = new NFC();
    }

    class Program
    {

        private static bool GetFullVarString(Type root, string[] varNamePath, out string valStr, int index = 0)
        {
            Object targetObj;
            bool status = false;
            if (index >= varNamePath.Length)    // Guard
            {
                valStr = "";
                return false;
            }

            targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(root);
            
            string varValStr = "";
            try
            {
                foreach (MemberInfo member in root.GetMembers())    // BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
                {
                    if (member.Name != varNamePath[index])
                        continue;

                    /* Have we found the variable we're looking for?    */
                    if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                    {
                        FieldInfo fieldInfo = ((FieldInfo)member);
                        if (fieldInfo.GetValue(targetObj) != null)
                        {
                            var miVal = fieldInfo.GetValue(targetObj);
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" Field Type: {0}", fieldInfo.FieldType.ToString()));
                            Type thisType = Type.GetType(fieldInfo.FieldType.FullName.ToString());
                            Boolean isStruct = thisType.IsValueType && !thisType.IsEnum && 
                                !(fieldInfo.FieldType.ToString().StartsWith("System"));
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" IsStruct: {0}", isStruct.ToString()));

                            if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsClass)
                            {
                                /* We've found a child class, so we need to change
                                 * the root type and step into it.
                                 */
                                Type newType = Type.GetType(fieldInfo.FieldType.FullName.ToString());
                                status = GetFullVarString(newType, varNamePath, out varValStr, index + 1);
                            }

                            else if (isStruct)
                            {
                                /* We've found a child struct, so we need to change
                                 * the root type and step into it.
                                 */
                                Type newType = Type.GetType(fieldInfo.FieldType.FullName.ToString());
                                status = GetFullVarString(newType, varNamePath, out varValStr, index + 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                varValStr = miVal.ToString();
                            }
                            status = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.NestedType)
                    {
                        Type nestedType = (Type)member;     // MemberInfo that is a NestedType is just a Type itself
                        status = GetFullVarString(nestedType, varNamePath, out varValStr, index + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
                status = false;
            }

            valStr = varValStr;
            return status;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PRD prd = new PRD();
            string fullVar, tstr;

            Type root = typeof(PRD);

            fullVar = "nfc.tst.x";
            GetFullVarString(root, fullVar.Split('.'), out tstr);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", fullVar, tstr));

            fullVar = "nfc.tst.t1.one";
            GetFullVarString(root, fullVar.Split('.'), out tstr);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", fullVar, tstr));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output shows that the variable 'x' at the base of the TST class displays fine, but the member of the t1 structure does not.

```
 Field Type: ConsoleApp5.NFC
 IsStruct: False
 Field Type: ConsoleApp5.TST
 IsStruct: False
 Field Type: System.UInt32
 IsStruct: False
nfc.tst.x = 7769
 Field Type: ConsoleApp5.NFC
 IsStruct: False
 Field Type: ConsoleApp5.TST
 IsStruct: False
 Field Type: ConsoleApp5.TST+S1_t
 IsStruct: True
 Field Type: System.UInt32
 IsStruct: False
nfc.tst.t1.one = 0
```

I'm thinking that maybe it has to do with using the Activator class on the non-class structure, but I have no idea.

Any help??

Comment: Why are you calling `Activator.CreateInstance` to create *new* instances of types, instead of inspecting the actual instances? Of course for a struct that's just going to yield a struct with all members initialized to default values, and not whatever values they would have gotten through the constructor of the container class. Even for classes this is not guaranteed to give the correct values (if members are changed after construction); it just happens to do what you expect in this particular scenario.

Comment: Basically, you need `FieldInfo.GetValue` here; `.CreateInstance` should occur just about nowhere.

Comment: It is my understanding that the .CreateInstance will give a reference to existing objects.  It seems to work for the 'x' variable.  I do use the FieldInfo.GetValue once I have reached the target field

Comment: Well, your understanding is wrong. :P As the name implies, `Activator.CreateInstance` always creates a new object. It "works" for `x` because `x` is instantiated through the constructor of `TST`, but try applying your function to `new TST { x = 42 }` (note: *not* within `NFT`, because then the whole thing gets initialized *there*).

Comment: The MS website says this about the Activator class: "Contains methods to create types of objects locally or remotely, or obtain references to existing remote objects."  I didn't see anything in the method descriptions that mentioned references, but...  I guess what I'm looking for is how to get the value of these structure members.

Comment: The docs are correct -- `Activator.CreateInstance` can create proxies to existing remote objects, but that really is the *only* scenario where `CreateInstance` will technically activate an "existing" object. When using it directly on a `Type`, you always get a new instance. You simply don't need to use this at all. Your recursion should be on specific `object` instances and not `Type`s.

Comment: You are right, of course about it creating a new instance.  I was just hoping to get the reference instead.  Any ideas on how to do that?  I don't know for sure how to obtain the object instance in this case.

Comment: A full demo would go too far, but [here's the gist](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1TT9h0). You can make this more "interesting" as necessary, but the basic idea is recursing over objects, not types.

Comment: Your link does not work - page not found

Comment: Slight typo where a `0` got added, [this is the right link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1TT9h).